# tcsh shortcut to move the cursor back to previous space

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tcsh, line-editor

I'm looking for a keyboard shortcut in `tcsh` to move the cursor back to the previous blank: not <kbd>ESC</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> which takes me back one word (for instance, in a path argument, to the previous path component) - I want to get to previous space or start of current path.

Comment: "Previous or start"?  That doesn't make sense.  Possibly you want Ctrl+b or Ctrl+a?

Comment: I think haimon wants to jump in “asd efg/hij” from letter “j” back to letter “e”. (Ctrl-a jumps to “a”, Alt-b jumps to “h”, Ctrl-b moves to “i”.) Maybe Alt-Ctrl-],space is the closest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you mean keyboard shortcut at the prompt of interactive `bash` shells, you could bind the `shell-backward-word` and `shell-forward-word` to some sequence of characters sent upon some key or combination of key presses.

Like if pressing <kbd>Ctrl-Left</kbd> sends the sequence `\e[1;5D` on your terminal like it does in `xterm`, you could do:

```
bind '"\e[1;5D": shell-backward-word'
bind '"\e[1;5D": shell-backward-word'
```

Note that it does not jump from blank to blank but considers shell quoting. So for instance in a line like

```
echo "foo 'bar baz' blah/bleh bloh
^   ^              ^         ^
```

It would jump to the locations marked above.

**Edit:** for `tcsh`, you have three options:

1. Use the equivalent to the `bash` definition above, either in `~/.cshrc` or in `/etc/csh.cshrc.local` to give all users the benefit.

   ```
   bindkey '\e[1;5D' backward-word
   bindkey '\e[1;5C' forward-word
   ```
2. Use the `vi` mode (with `bindkey -v`) and use the `B` and `W` keys in normal mode just like in `vi`.
3. In `emacs` mode (the default, reenabled with `bindkey -e`) like for `bash`, bind the corresponding widgets (`vi-word-back` and `vi-word-fwd`):

   ```
   bindkey '\e[1;5C' vi-word-fwd
   bindkey '\e[1;5D' vi-word-back
   ```

Note that those are like `vi`'s `B` and `W`, so they're for jumping between blank separated words, not shell tokens (like quoted strings) like in the `bash` solution above.

Comment: Yes Stephane this is what I'm looking for ! but I dont have bind command in my shell, I found bindkey and it does not understand it...any idea?

Comment: @haimon, Your shell must be either `tcsh` or `zsh`. Could you please find out (`ps` should tell you) and update your question?

Comment: Hi - it is tcsh according to ps.

Comment: Hi - is there a VI shorcurt to jump to previous space or start of text (aaa bb/cccc - jump from en of line to space between b and a)

Comment: @haimon. I don't think so. See the output of `bindkey -l` or `man tcsh` for the list of widgets. But you can use a macro (`bindkey -s`) to do the `B` followed by `h`.

Comment: Found it !!!   thanks Stephane ! it is "bindkey ^[^[[D vi-word-back"

Answer (score 0):

I think you're wanting `CTRL-B` which in bash moves the cursor back one character. `CTRL-f` will then move you back forward. [Here is a quick reference](http://www.ice2o.com/bash_quick_ref.html) for these shortcuts.

Comment: Usually also mapped to left arrow? :)

Comment: Depends on what type of Unix or what distribution of Linux the OP is on. Arrow keys aren't always mapped, that's something you usually only see on the more user-friendly Linux distros.

Comment: Sure, that's why I wrote *usually*. I think percentage of live systems that have it like this will be 90%+.

Comment: I have about 50 Solaris servers that don't fit that description. Traditional Unix still has a large install base that GNU/Linux as a whole is just now approaching parity with.

Answer (score 0):

"ESC-left-arrow : go to beginning of left word"
bindkey ^[^[[D vi-word-back

for example:
cd a/b/c/d 
ESC+left will take you from end of line to the space between "cd" and "a"